# MongoDB not updating in node js using graphql

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

I'm doing an update mutation in graphql in front end

```
mutation updateSetting($updateSetting:CoSettingInput,$id:String) {
     updateConSettings(input:$updateSetting,settingId:$id){
         _id                        
         Local                        
         Token
         Credentials
         Port
         Host
         Auth                        
     }
}
```

Variables passed from front end for graphql

```
{
  "updateSetting": {
     "Local " :"asdasdkk"                      
     "Token":"asdasdkk"    
     "Credentials":"asdasdkk"    
     "Port":"asdasdkk"    
     "Host":"asdasdkk"    
     "Auth" :"asdasdkk"    
   },
   "id": "5d96e98e7a921f0414619ad1"
}
```

Backend MongoDB querying in node js

```
input CoSettingInput{
    Local                        
    Token
    Credentials
    Port
    Host
    Auth 
}
updateConSettings(input:ConSettingInput,settingId:String):ConSettings
    async updateConSettings(root,{
       input,
       settingId
    }){
       console.log(input,settingId)
       const updateSetting=await ConSchema.updateOne(
           {_id:ObjectId(settingId)},
           {CoSettingInput:input}                
       ).exec();
            console.log("ErrorupdateSetting",updateSetting)
            if(!updateSetting){
                throw new Error("Error- Cannot update the setting")
            }
       return updateSetting
    }
```

I've  console and receive the data at the back end but it doesn't update.

```
            {ok:0,n:0,nModified:0}
```

I google nothings working out I find no errors too to crack to the solution.
I'm stuck passed 3 days :(
Can anyone please lemme know as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `{ok:0,n:0,nModified :0 }` it can find the matching document for the given query. So check `{_id:ObjectId(settingId)}` is constructing properly

Comment: @Subburaj yeah its reciving the id. how do i check the construction is proper?

Comment: Can you do `console.log(ObjectId(settingId))` and see how its printing

Comment: @Subburaj I'd console thats -> settingId,ObjectId(settingId)  -> '5d96e98e7a921f0414619ad1' 5d96e98e7a921f0414619ad1 -> respectivly i receive though receiving it doesnt update

Comment: Sure with this id data is there in MongoDB?? My Guess is that ObjectId is creating problem

Comment: Yeah DB does have Data with that id "5d96e98e7a921f0414619ad1". without objectId too it doesn't update

Comment: please read my pervious comment data is there in db there's only one record and that's there.

Comment: Ok. `_id:ObjectId(settingId)` ObjectId does u sed any npm or using inBuilt??

Comment: inBuilt from mongodb

Comment: Can you show how u imported ObjectID??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200582/discussion-between-tested-and-subburaj).

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the $set in your query try for the following

```
ConSchemas.updateOne(
           {_id:ObjectId(settingId)},
           {$set:{CoSettingInput:input}})
```

But `$set` will work for individual key for whole document update you can use

```
ConSchemas.replaceOne(
               {_id:ObjectId(settingId)},
               {CoSettingInput:input})
```

But in replaceOne you will lose all previous keys, the new only will be updated.